# Regex in php array needs to pass string to function

Tags: php, arrays, bbcode

I've created my own bbcode for my site so we can use certain codes to reference some php functions, but now I've hit a problem.

I'd like to use [photos=date,2013-08-21] as bbcode, which would then would be processed like this

```
"/\[photos\=(.*?),(.*?)\]/e" => "showPhotos($1,$2)",
```

That's one line of our bbcode rules.

So we should be getting showPhotos(date,2013-08-21) being passed into the function.

But what's happening is that before it's getting to the showPhotos function, php is subtracting the numbers in the date, so it's passing showPhotos(date,1992).

How can I force that to remain a string as it's passed into the showPhotos function?

Comment: Ah please don't use the `e` modifier. It's deprecated by now and you should be using `preg_replace_callback()`. It's safer and you have more control of the flow.

Comment: I havn't worked with this e-modifier before, so my suggestions here are pure guessing. But what if you add string quotes to the value-side of the array? I'm guessing it is processed like eval? If so "/\[photos\=(.*?),(.*?)\]/e" => "showPhotos($1,'$2')" should do the trick. Note the single quotes around $2. But as HamZa says using the preg_replace_callback() is probably the best way to go.